Connecting to Lando database container from non lando container
I need some help in regard of connecting to lando database from a separate non-lando container. Maybe this is easy? or maybe I'm doing it the wrong way.
So basically, I have an initial lando wordpress with the following .lando.yml and everything works fine, I can see the wordpress site running, and mysql database running. and I can use sequelpro gui client from host machine to connect to lando database with host: 127.0.0.1 port 63000
name: my-first-wordpress-app
recipe: wordpress
config:
  webroot: wordpress
services:
  appserver:
    build_as_root:
      - sed 's|mozilla\/AddTrust_External_Root.crt|#mozilla\/AddTrust_External_Root.crt|g' -i /etc/ca-certificates.conf
      - cp /app/mycert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
      - chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mycert.crt
      - update-ca-certificates  

Now, I'm trying to see if I can connect to lando mysql database from different wordpress container (NON LANDO, straight up docker image from wordpress). So I stop lando wordpress application, while keeping the database container running and then run
docker compose up -d with the following docker-compose.yml file. Now I can go to localhost:8000 and see there's wordpress but it says can't connect to database, which I assume the way I set up the connection is wrong.
  # wordpress
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: 127.0.0.1:63000 # I'm pretty sure this is the wrong one
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: someuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: somepassword


